# hibernate query result the same after altering db externally

Tags: hibernate, caching, jakarta-ee

I got a problem during querying a list of items using hibernate, logically it should return the same result if no other user or an external app changed the DB contents - however it returns the same result even after changing the DB contents which it doesn't make any sense, i searched a lot about this problem and some of them said that this problem related to caching, so i disabled the second level cache using hibernate.cfg.xml and set the cache mode in the session to IGONRE - after all of that nothing changed.

```
<property name="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">false</property>

session.setCacheMode(CacheMode.IGNORE);
```

i'm using hibernate in an EJB module (StatelessSessionBean) - and querying the results in presentation tier (Web module - JSF)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, if the objects are already in the session, Hibernate will give you the already loaded instances. Which might be older.

Maybe try `session.refresh(obj)`

Another issue might be the isolation level of your transaction.
Read about Transaction Isolation Levels here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isolation_(database_systems)#Isolation_levels

For example if you have SERIALIZABLE, then you will only see the data as it was when you started your reading Transaction.